# Is it possible to merge these similar functions into one function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have 3 (and soon more) functions that each do the exact same thing, but control different enumerated divs/variables depending on which div the mousewheel event is triggered over.  I'm curious if there are any tricks to compact these very similar dumb functions into one smart function.  Each div needs its own `#bigwrapperN` , `#wrapperN`, `opacityN`,  and `colorcounterN`.

```
$('#bigwrapper1').mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
    if (delta > 0) {
        opacity1 = opacity1 + .05;
        $('#wrapper1').css('background', "rgba("+colors[colorcounter1]+","+opacity1+")");
    } else if (delta < 0) {
        opacity1 = opacity1 - .05;
        $('#wrapper1').css('background',"rgba("+colors[colorcounter1]+","+opacity1+")");
    }
});

$('#bigwrapper2').mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
    if (delta > 0) {
        opacity2 = opacity2 + .05;
        $('#wrapper2').css('background', "rgba("+colors[colorcounter2]+","+opacity2+")");
    } else if (delta < 0) {
        opacity2 = opacity2 - .05;
        $('#wrapper2').css('background', "rgba("+colors[colorcounter2]+","+opacity2+")");
    }
});

$('#bigwrapper3').mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
    if (delta > 0) {
        opacity3 = opacity3 + .05;
        $('#wrapper3').css('background', "rgba("+colors[colorcounter3]+","+opacity3+")");
    } else if (delta < 0) {
        opacity3 = opacity3 - .05;
        $('#wrapper3').css('background', "rgba("+colors[colorcounter3]+","+opacity3+")");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Attribute Starts with Selector.`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) Try:

```
$('div[id^=bigwrapper]').mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
    var i = $(this).attr("id").split("bigwrapper")[1];
    if (delta > 0) {
   opacity[i] = opacity[i] + .05;       
    $('div[id="wrapper'+i+'"]').css('background', "rgba("+eval('colors[colorcounter'+i+']')+","+opacity[i]+")");
} else if (delta < 0) {
    opacity[i] = opacity[i] - .05;
    $('div[id="wrapper'+i+'"]').css('background', "rgba("+eval('colors[colorcounter'+i+']')+","+opacity[i]+")");
}
});
```

Comment: Looks like I need to use `eval()` to create dynamic variable names as the above code doesn't work. Ie, `eval('opacity'+i)` instead of `opacity+'i'`

Comment: @DrewP84 I dont think we need eval(). can you post your code in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Not sure I can post it all in a fiddle.  Just view the site here: http://www.artfuladvection.com/project/NOAA/ndfdGraph/bloom.php  It's all working except the mousewheel event.  I cannot assign a dynamic variable name to the left of the equation.   I've made these changes: `eval('opacity'+i) = eval('opacity'+i) + .05;`, `$('#wrapper+"i"').css('background', "rgba("+eval('colors[colorcounter'+i+']')+","+eval('opacity'+i)+")");`

Comment: I think I'll ditch the single variables and create an array called opacity, then I can just call single variables like so `opacity[i]`.

Comment: Can you update your code to what I have posted as an answer below, so I can accept it as the answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The selectors works like in CSS so you can use:

```
$('#bigwrapper1, #bigwrapper2, #bigwrapper3').mousewheel( ...
```

But for this type of tasks it's always preferred to use classes:

```
$('.someClass').mousewheel( ...
```

This way you can use classes also for the inner wrappers:

```
$(this).filter('.wrapper').css(...
```

Comment: True, but `$('div[id*="bigwrapper"]').mousewheel(` would be more efficient. Still, what about changing the unique names of 
`#wrapperN`, `opacityN`, and `colorcounterN` inside the function ?

Comment: @DrewP84 performance of a function called only at the beginning is not such a problem unless you've several mbytes of DOM to traverse. I've updated for the inner wrappers

Answer (score 1):

you could also store the opacity and colorcounter information in the data() of the bigwrapper

```
$('div[id^=bigwrapper]').mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
    var data = $(this).data(), background;

    data.opacity += (delta > 0 ? .05 : delta < 0 ? -.05 : 0);

    background = "rgba("+colors[data.colorcounter]+","+data.opacity+")";
    //$(this).find('div[id^=wrapper]')
    $(this).find('.wrapper').css('background', background);

});
```

Comment: What about changing the unique names of `#wrapperN`, `opacityN`, and `colorcounterN` inside the function ? This does not address that.

Comment: Ah Agreed, I thought the differences were just for example.

Comment: Thanks, this is a useful alternative.

Answer (score 1):

**This solution worked:  Thanks @Unknown - you provided the core of the answer, so I'll accept yours.**

```
$('div[id^=bigwrapper]').mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
    var i = $(this).attr("id").split("bigwrapper")[1];
    if (delta > 0) {
       opacity[i] = opacity[i] + .05;       
        $('div[id="wrapper'+i+'"]').css('background', "rgba("+eval('colors[colorcounter'+i+']')+","+opacity[i]+")");
    } else if (delta < 0) {
        opacity[i] = opacity[i] - .05;
        $('div[id="wrapper'+i+'"]').css('background', "rgba("+eval('colors[colorcounter'+i+']')+","+opacity[i]+")");
    }
});
```